# How to extract lines if any one of the two match string matches?

Tags: text-processing

I have a file where I have few lines of information that contains the country name as shown below.

```
$cat country.txt

max_china_clean_foo
man_india_raw_bar
max_us_clean_bax
max_uk_raw_bar
max_canada_raw_foo
max_au_clean_bar
```

I want to extract only the country names from this file. I am currently using the below code to extract country name in a for loop

```
val=${val#*_}
val=${val%_clean*}
echo $val
```

But the output produced has only `china, us` and `au` country names and hence I have to repeat the similar code with minor modifications to extract the remaining countries like below

```
val=${val#*_}
val=${val%_raw*}
echo $val
```

This is not a clear way of coding, I know and hence need your help to extract the country names from all the lines that has either `clean` or `raw` string in it.

Is there a way using awk or sed to extract all the country names with two match keys? My output should look like this

```
china
india
us
uk
canada
au
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[I wouldn't use a shell loop to process text](/q/169716).

Here, you can just do:

```
cut -d _ -f 2 < country.txt
```

Or if the input may contain lines without `_` characters:

```
awk -F _ 'NF >= 2 {print $2}' < country.txt
```

If the country name may contain `_` character and you want instead to return the part of the line in between the first `_` and the first occurrence of `_raw` or `_clean` after that, you could do:

```
perl -ne 'print $1 if s/^[^_]*_(.*?)_(clean|raw)/' < country.txt
```

Or with GNU `grep`:

```
grep -Po '^[^_]*_\K.*?(?=_clean|_raw)' < country.txt
```

With `-P` (provided `grep` has been built with PCRE support), the regexp is a perl-compatible one. In those regexps, `\K` resets the start of the matched string, and `(?=...)` is a look-ahead operator, that is it looks if the rest of the string matches `...` without that part being included in the matched portion. `-o` makes `grep` output the matched portion, so  here it prints what matches the `.*?` above which is the non-greedy equivalent of `.*`, that is a sequence of 0 or more characters, as short as possible, in this case following a sequence of 0 or more underscores (`[^_]*`) found at the start of the line (`^`) followed by an underscore and assuming it's followed by either `_raw` or `_clean`.

With `pcregrep`, you can also write it:

```
pcregrep -o1 '^[^_]*_(.*?)_(clean|raw)'
```

With `-o1`, it prints the portion matched by the first `(...)`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you please explain the grep command?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way in awk style

```
awk -F'_' '/clean|raw/{ print $2}'
```